# How to Auto Split Text Within Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, split

I want to have an object that accepts some input string with delimeters like "dog:cat:whale" and want the property inside "splittedText" to be an array of post-split input objects `"spittedText[0] = dog, spittedText[1] = cat, spittedText[2] = whale".`

The following is generic pseudocode of what I want to accomplish, but doesnt work...

```
function someObject(input) {
    this.splittedText=input.split(':');
}
```

To test, I should be able to do this:

```
theObject = new someObject("dog:cat:whale");
alert(someObject(theObject.splittedText[0])); // should print out dog
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling the function again.

```
alert(theObject.splittedText[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var someObj = new SomeObject("dog:cat:whale");

function SomeObject(str){
    this.splittedText = str.split(':');
}

alert(someObj.splittedText);
```